# Choose to search from optional word (regex)

Tags: regex

I am receiving emails that can really vary on their text.

They can either come like this:

```
Example Product

1,00

50,38

50,38

In Bearbeitung

Versendet: Dieser
 Artikel wurde soeben versendet.

In Bearbeitung: Dieser
 Artikel befindet sich in Bearbeitung.

Herr
Matthew Example
Example Street 19
3333 London
England

Please find
enclosed your invoice in a pdf document.
```

or like this:

```
Example Product

1,00

50,38

50,38

Matthew Example
Example Street 19
3333 London
England

Please find
enclosed your invoice in a pdf document.
```

I have a solution that works for the second email perfectly:

```
^\d{1,9},\d{1,2}\s*\n((?:(?!\d+,\d+$).*\n)*)Please find
```

The reason that the pattern does not match the first email is because the number comes before "in Bearbeitung". How do I solve this? *I want to capture the address for each email, including everything about the recipient.*

Comment: What is it that you want to match/capture?

Comment: The address for each email.

Comment: In the first format will the line before the address always end in `... in Bearbeitung` ?

Comment: No it can vary.

Comment: Will the address always begin with Herr/Frau?

Comment: It can begin with all of these '\n(Female[\s\S]*?|Male[\s\S]*?|Frau[\s\S]*?|Herr[\s\S]*?)\n\n

Comment: Crazy email right?

Comment: Sometimes it will not even begin with any of them and just the first name, so the solution in the comment above is redundant since they then made even more combinations for address and name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
((?:^.+$\n)+)\nPlease find
```

[Here is the test](https://regex101.com/r/b6daBN/1)

How it works?  I noticed the address are surrounded by additional empty lines at both top and bottom, and followed by *"Please find"*, so if you can keep this format then this method can work.

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind going in a little more detail on your written code? I had this idea but couldn't get it to work...